# Exception in Replacement of symbols java

Tags: java, replace, symbols

I have the following, because i want to replace every special character(!,',-,[] etc) with space from a file. But i want to keep the .  and the ,

How can i add an exception for only those 2 punctuations(comma and dot)?

```
content = content.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ")
```

Comment: What do you mean by symbols, All special characters ?

Comment: yes exactly, i will correct it @ShubhWIP

Comment: Add them to the negated character class `[^a-zA-Z0-9,.]` But this will match any character other than the listed. You can also specify what you want to match `[]['-]` and replace that with a space.

Comment: [^a-zA-Z0-9,.] that actually worked for me, thank you very much @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `,` and `.` to the negated character class.

```
content = content.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,.]", " ");
```

If you want to remove multiple consecutive chars and leave a single space, you can use a multiplier `[^a-zA-Z0-9,.]+`

Another option could be more specific by listing the chars that you want to replace. In Java with the doubled backslash:

```
content = content.replaceAll("[]\\['!-]", " ");
```